# How do I create a Parser data?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I am trying to learn how can I do a parser for expressions in Haskell and I found this code (below), but I don't even know how to use it.

I tried with: expr (Add (Num 5) (Num  2)) , but it needs a "Parser" data type.

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String
import Text.Parsec.Expr
import Text.Parsec.Token
import Text.Parsec.Language

data Expr = Num Int | Var String | Add Expr Expr | Sub Expr Expr | Mul Expr Expr | Div Expr Expr deriving Show

expr :: Parser Expr
expr = buildExpressionParser table factor
  <?> "expression"
table = [[op "*" Mul AssocLeft, op "/" Div AssocLeft],
      [op "+" Add AssocLeft, op "-" Sub AssocLeft]]
      where
        op s f assoc = Infix (do{ string s; return f}) assoc
factor = do{ char '('
        ; x <- expr
        ; char ')'
        ; return x}
    <|> number
    <|> variable
    <?> "simple expression"
number :: Parser Expr
number = do{ ds<- many1 digit
      ; return (Num (read ds))}
  <?> "number"
variable :: Parser Expr
variable = do{ ds<- many1 letter
        ; return (Var ds)}
  <?> "variable"
```

Solution: readExpr input = parse expr "name for error messages" input
and use readExpr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `parse` which will run a `Parser` on an input string and return an `Either ParseError Expr`. I put a simple usage below where I turn that `ParseError` into a string and pass it along

```
readExpr :: String -> Either String Expr
readExpr input = case parse expr "name for error messages" input of
   Left err -> Left $ "Oh noes parsers are failing: " ++ show err -- Handle error
   Right a  -> Right a -- Handle success
```

There are a few other functions, such as `parseFromFile`, which let you shorthand a few common patterns, to find them, check out the parsec [haddock](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec)

Comment: I think it should be Right a??

Comment: No, I'm feeding it into something which returns an `Either` as well. I'd end up writing `Right a -> Right a`

Comment: @jozefg: No, he is right. `ParseError` and `String` are different types, so you need to write `Right a -> Right a` to change the type from `Either ParseError Expr` to `Either String Expr`. Otherwise, it won't typecheck.